# Can't load dll in linux gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile my code with a DLL i made and I get the error below when i write `./prog`

> ./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libctest.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I followed [the tutorial here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) and my mono app has no problem loading the dll and calling the functions. The key parts of the tutorial were

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c *.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libctest.so.1 -o libctest.so.1.0   *.o
mv libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib
ln -sf /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libctest.so.1
ln -sf /opt/lib/libctest.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libctest.so
```

My C# code does

```
[DllImport("path/to/CDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void test();
```

I built with

```
gcc -Wall -L/opt/lib main.c -lctest -o prog
```

This is the first thing i changed. prog.c to main.c. From there I simply run with `./prog` to get the error at the top of this question. I do this as root so there shouldn't be permission issues. I also chmod 755 the so's. What am I doing wrong? This is opensuse. I had to create the `/opt/lib` so I am thinking this path isn't registered where it should be

Comment: Try adding /opt/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dynamic linker `ld.so` will not look in `/opt/lib` by default when attempting to resolve library dependencies.  You have to tell the linker about the non-standard library directories or add the `/opt/lib` path to your `prog` binary.

eg

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib ./prog
```

or, link `prog` with the `-rpath` linker option.  This provides an additional path for the linker to search when resolving locations of shared objects.

```
gcc -Wall -L/opt/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/lib main.c -lctest -o prog
```

You can use the `ldd` command on a binary to show the locations of shared libraries.

```
ldd prog
```

This will currently show that `libctest.so` cannot be found.  With an additional search path, the following command should show that all libraries are resolved:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib ldd prog
```